# How to instantiate object with custom auto-incrementing field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on an application which needs to import some data from an old database - let's say IDs one through one million. The IDs from the old database will be loaded into an integer column which is unique but will no longer be the primary key. While loading old data (and afterwards) entries created in the new system should be assigned a serial ID starting at three million so that there is definitely space to import all the old entries over some time without getting collisions.

This is currently implemented with a a migration doing `ALTER SEQUENCE […] START 3000000` and a custom field type:

```
import typing
from django.db import models, ConnectionHandler
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs


class SerialField(models.IntegerField):
    def db_type(self, connection: ConnectionHandler) -> str:
        return 'serial'

    def get_db_prep_save(self, value: typing.Optional[int], connection: ConnectionHandler) -> typing.Union[int, AsIs]:
        if isinstance(value, int):
            # so we can override the default with our own value
            return value

        return AsIs('default')
```

The problem with the current solution is that when creating an object having a `SerialField` the value of the field is `None` rather than the actual value saved in the database. Can I change `SerialField` so that I don't have to manually sync the returned object to get the serial value, or is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I’d like to think the serial value is incremented by the DBMS, so object creation in code won’t actually do that until you try to persist said object in which case it’s value is obtained. Short of 2 DB calls (persist, fetch ID), I can’t think of a good way to achieve this.